# libgit2: Failed to resolve path when creating a repo

Tags: c, git, libgit2

For a project I am working on, I am trying to use libgit2.
For the moment, I am just trying to create a repo using `git_repository_init` but it fails with the following error message :

```
Error: -1/2: Failed to resolve path 'D:/Workspace/<project_name>/test/.git/': Invalid argument
```

The code is the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "git2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    git_libgit2_init();

    git_repository *repo;
    git_repository_init_options opts = GIT_REPOSITORY_INIT_OPTIONS_INIT;
    opts.flags |= GIT_REPOSITORY_INIT_MKDIR;
    int err = git_repository_init_ext(&repo, "D:/Workspace/<project_name>/test", &opts);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        const git_error *e = giterr_last();
        std::cerr << "Error: " << err << "/" << e->klass << ": " << e->message << std::endl;
    }

    git_repository_free(repo);

    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

The .git directory in the test directory is still created but it's empty.
I have tried with relative and absolute path and also Unix and windows path but the result seem to always be the same.

Also, when executing libgit2_clar, a lot of test fail always with the same error : "error -1 - Failed to resolve path 'attr': Invalid argument".

libgit2 and the previous code has been compiled and executed on a Windows XP 32bit using MinGW with gcc 4.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP is not supported by libgit2.  Support ended in [v0.21.0 in 2014](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/releases/tag/v0.21.0):

> Top-level Improvements
>
> - **We've dropped support for Windows XP.** We're evil like that.

Answer (score 0):

The *repo_path* parameter of *git_repository_init_ext* isn't legal because 
it contains the chars '<' '>' . 
Try to make new directory with the above chars and you get error message.

Comment: <project_name> is just there so I don't have to disclose the name of the project I'm working on. The real name contain only legal alphanumeric chars.